# Data migration tool hanging with no error. What can I do?

Tags: magento2.2, data-migration-tool

I am trying to migrate a database from 1.9.3.1 ce to 2.2.2 ee using the data migration tool. I have done this before and had to deal with errors but I am not getting any errors. When it gets to this step-

[INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Map Step]: started 13%

it stalls. It happened yesterday so I restored the database and started over and it happened at exactly 13% again. I let it run for 12 hours to make sure it had enough time. Our store has about 5k customers, 25k items, and 15k orders so I don't think it is too big. Any ideas?

Comment: Both Source and Destination DB is on same RDS/DB server?

Comment: No, I am going from remote to local server.

Comment: there must be some error in any log

Comment: @MagenX I have been looking through the logs to find anything but nothing has showed up. I looked in the access and error logs. Is there another one I should look at?

Comment: Have you tried local to local ? I mean you try to put both the DB on local and try if it stuck or not at the same position.

Answer (score 1):

you have 3 options to understand this issue:

1 - open another session and check `top`, see if process is actually running:

```
31570 test+  20   0  753532 127000  51552 S   1.7  3.3   0:27.43 php bin/magento migrate:data -a /home/testmigration/public_html/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to+
```

2 - `starce` process `31570` :

```
strace -p 31570 -s 99999
```

you will see whats going on inside, something like this:

```
poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=11, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(11, "\1\0\0\1\1V\0\0\2\3def\2mg$catalog_product_entity_media_gallery\tentity_id\tentity_id\f?\0\n\0\0\0\3)@\0\0\0\5\0\0\3\376\0\0\2\0\5\0\0\4\0041189\5\0\0\5\376\0\0\2\0", 17222, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 122
sendto(11, "i\0\0\0\3SELECT `mg`.`entity_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` AS `mg` WHERE (mg.value_id = '8221')", 109, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 109
poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=11, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(11, "\1\0\0\1\1V\0\0\2\3def\2mg$catalog_product_entity_media_gallery\tentity_id\tentity_id\f?\0\n\0\0\0\3)@\0\0\0\5\0\0\3\376\0\0\2\0\5\0\0\4\0041189\5\0\0\5\376\0\0\2\0", 17100, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 122
```

3 - install `mytop` and see database transactions.

```
MySQL on localhost (5.7.21-20)                                                                                                load 0.37 0.14 0.13 4/401 31777 up 2+16:11:30 [10:39:50]
 Queries: 43.2k   qps:    0 Slow:     0.0         Se/In/Up/De(%):    11/26/01/00 
 Sorts:     0 qps now:    1 Slow qps: 0.0  Threads:    2 (   2/   4) 00/14/00/00 
 Key Efficiency: 92.6%  Bps in/out:  90.8/ 58.2   Now in/out: 546.1k/535.6k

       Id      User         Host/IP         DB       Time    Cmd    State Query                                                                                                       
       --      ----         -------         --       ----    ---    ----- ----------                                                                                                  
      262      m2u_       localhost       m2d_          1  Query   update INSERT INTO report_event (`event_id`,`logged_at`,`event_type_id`,`object_id`,`subject_id`,`subtype`,`store_i
      264      root       localhost      mysql          0  Query starting show full processlist
```

obviously some migrations can take long time, depends on data amount, connection speed and server specs

> p.s. truncate logs, events, reports and other non-important or
>   temporary data that you dont need in magento 2.

Comment: I started over and installed mytop. I watched it from the start and could see all the queries. Once it got to that same table it hung and said ID 1270 - User root - DB magento - Time 0 - Cmd Query starting show full process list. And that is where it sits.

Comment: just strace this php pid and you will see, mysql process can be in sleep state for long time